# Can you use possessive indicators on pronouns that already have a possessive version of itself in Dovahzul?

Tags: dovahzul

In Dovahzul, you can show possession by using `se`, `do`, `ro`, or `dro`. However, the pronouns already have possessive versions of themselves (e.g. `You` goes to `Your`).

Would something like `hisedok`/`hi do dok` work instead of `hin dok`?

In English `You's` rather than `Your` wouldn't be grammatically correct, and Dovahzul is remarkably similar to English, but there may be an exception to this.